# How can I turn this nested if function into functional style programming with Ramda in Javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, prisma, ramda.js

I was looking at the code in Prisma for softdelete middleware:

```js
  prisma.$use(async (params, next) => {
    // Check incoming query type
    if (params.model == 'Post') {
      if (params.action == 'delete') {
        // Delete queries
        // Change action to an update
        params.action = 'update'
        params.args['data'] = { deleted: true }
      }
      if (params.action == 'deleteMany') {
        // Delete many queries
        params.action = 'updateMany'
        if (params.args.data != undefined) {
          params.args.data['deleted'] = true
        } else {
          params.args['data'] = { deleted: true }
        }
      }
    }
    return next(params)
  })
```

**The steps it takes is:**
Check if Post -> if it's a 'delete' or 'deleteMany' then change action to 'update' and set deleted to true.

The nested if's seems not ideal and it seemed that this would be cleaner using a functional style, so I used Ramda to try and make it functional:

```js
const model = lensProp('model')
const action = lensProp('action')
const argsData = compose(lensProp('args'), lensProp('data'))
const cView = curry(view)
const modelView = cView(model)
const actionView = cView(action)
const _shouldBeModified = (models, actions, p) => and(
    includes(modelView(p), models),
    includes(actionView(p), actions)  
)
const shouldBeModified = curry(_shouldBeModified)
const timeElapsed = Date.now();
const today = new Date(timeElapsed);

const softDelete = (models, actions, params) => ifElse(
  shouldBeModified(models, actions), 
  pipe(
    set(argsData, { deleted: true, deletedAt: today.toISOString()}), 
    set(action, 'update')
  ),
  identity
)(params)
```

I can then call it like this:

```js
softDelete(['Post'],['delete', 'deleteMany'],params)

/*
 returns: {"action": "update", "args": {"data": {"deleted": true, "deletedAt": "2022-04-17T19:49:00.294Z"}}, "model": "Post"}
*/
```

All of that said, I'm new to Ramda and it seems like my approach is messy, can someone help me clean this up?

Comment: I really doubt Ramda will be able to help you with this.  Ramda is all about avoiding mutation.  Here you want to mutate your `params` input.  I don't think there's a match.  I don't know `prisma`.  If it has an immutable reducer version, perhaps there's something Ramda could do.

Comment: According to the [Prisma docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#reference-32), the params object is a pojo, so you can mutate or create a new one, as long as you pass return the result of calling `next(params)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `R.when` with `R.where` to check if the `params` should be updated. If so, use `R.evolve` to update them.

Pass an `actions` object, instead of an array, so the code can map the `update` / `updateMany` according to the original action.

```js
const { curry, when, where, includes, __, keys, evolve, prop, mergeDeepLeft } = R

const actionsMap = { delete: 'update', deleteMany: 'updateMany' };

const softDelete = curry((models, actions, params) => when(
  where({
    model: includes(__, models),
    action: includes(__, keys(actions))
  }),
  evolve({
    action: prop(__, actions),
    args: mergeDeepLeft({ data: { deleted: true, deletedAt: new Date().toISOString() }})
  })
)(params))

const params = {"action": "deleteMany", "args": { data: { something: 5 } }, "model": "Post"}

const result = softDelete(['Post'], actionsMap, params)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: I think Ramda really needs a `why` function.  Your `when` and `where` looks... incomplete.  :-)

Comment: WH functions :)

Comment: Perfect, this is what I was hoping for and uses some functions I'm not familiar with, I'll have to take some time to grok it. Thanks!